# How to determine the date one day prior to a given date in Java?

Tags: java, date, leap-year

I am assuming Java has some built-in way to do this.

**Given a date, how can I determine the date one day prior to that date?**

For example, suppose I am given 3/1/2009. The previous date is 2/28/2009. If I had been given 3/1/2008, the previous date would have been 2/29/2008.

Comment: The over/under on the number of answers suggesting Joda Time is 3.5. I'll take the over.

Comment: sleep(-86400); Date.getDate() ?  :-)

Comment: @mmyers: I had looked at Joda Time, but I thought surely Java's library could handle this simple task on its own. Maybe not...

Comment: @William Brendel: Usually, that doesn't make a difference. Looks like I'm losing my bet this time though.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use the Calendar interface.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(myDate);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,-1);
Date oneDayBefore= cal.getTime();
```

Doing "addition" in this way guarantees you get a valid date.  This is valid for 1st of the year as well, e.g. if `myDate` is January 1st, 2012, `oneDayBefore` will be December 31st, 2011.

Comment: Btw, `Calendar.getInstance()` would probably be a bit more generic way to achieve the instance of Calendar.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net), a very good Java library to manipulate dates:

```
DateTime result = dt.minusDays(1);
```

Answer (score 5):

With java.time.Instant

```
Date.from(Instant.now().minus(Duration.ofDays(1)))
```

Answer (score 4):

The java.util.Calendar class allows us to add or subtract any number of day/weeks/months/whatever from a date. Just use the add() method:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Example:

```
Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar(2009, 3, 1);
date.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import static java.util.Calendar.*;


public class TestDayBefore {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(YEAR, 2009);
        calendar.set(MONTH, MARCH);
        calendar.set(DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime()); //prints Sun Mar 01 23:20:20 EET 2009
        calendar.add(DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime()); //prints Sat Feb 28 23:21:01 EET 2009

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the [date4j](http://www.date4j.net) library :

```
DateTime yesterday = today.minusDays(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This would help.

```
getPreviousDateForGivenDate("2015-01-19", 10);
getPreviousDateForGivenDate("2015-01-19", -10);

public static String getPreviousDateForGivenDate(String givenDate, int datesPriorOrAfter) {
    String saleDate = getPreviousDate(datesPriorOrAfter);

    try {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String[] arr = givenDate.split("-", 3);
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]), Integer.parseInt(arr[1])-1, Integer.parseInt(arr[2]));
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, datesPriorOrAfter);    
        saleDate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error at getPreviousDateForGivenDate():"+e.getMessage());
    }

    return saleDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## ***java.time***

The java.time API introduced with Java-8 (March 2014) supplants the error-prone and outdated `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`. It is recommended to stop using the legacy date-time API and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

### How to parse a date string using java.time API?

Use [`LocalDate#parse(CharSequence text, DateTimeFormatter formatter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) to parse a date string which is not in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. However, a date string already in ISO 8601 format (`yyyy-MM-dd`), can be parsed using [`LocalDate parse(CharSequence text)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-).

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String strDateTime = "3/1/2009";
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(strDateTime, formatter);
        System.out.println(date);

        strDateTime = "2009-03-01";
        date = LocalDate.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2009-03-01
2009-03-01
```

### How to get the previous date using java.time API?

The simplest option is to use [`LocalDate#minusDays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#minusDays-long-). You can use one of the overloaded `LocalDate#minus` functions as well but they are there mainly to subtract for other time units e.g. hour, minute etc.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        System.out.println(today);
        LocalDate previousDay = today.minusDays(1);
        System.out.println(previousDay);

        // Alternatively
        previousDay = today.minus(Period.ofDays(1));
        System.out.println(previousDay);

        // Alternatively
        previousDay = today.minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        System.out.println(previousDay);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-10-13
2022-10-12
2022-10-12
2022-10-12
```

**Putting together**:

```
LocalDate previousDay = LocalDate.parse(
                            "3/1/2009", 
                            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u", Locale.ENGLISH)
                        ).minusDays(1); // 2009-02-28
```

### Just in case

Just in case, you want the result to be formatted in the same format as the date string, use [`DateTimeFormatter#format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#format-java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor-) e.g.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter= DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(previousDay.format(formatter)); // 2/28/2009

// Alternatively
System.out.println(formatter.format(previousDay)); // 2/28/2009
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Some useful links**:

1. [Never use Date-Time formatting/parsing API without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573)
2. I [prefer u to y](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) with `DateTimeFormatter`.